# iptables policy & saving in RHEL

Tags: iptables, redhat, hardening

As part of a "Hardening" task, I need to run

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

On our servers. Normally we would run this command and then run `/sbin/iptables-save` to implement the new policy. However as soon as I ran iptables -P OUTPUT DROP my SSH disconnected.
Is this due to the OS being RHEL?
How do I configure this machine to allow my IP address through?

Comment: Your server already has a firewall. You should look at it before attempting this so-called "Hardening" task. The task probably does not make sense for RHEL as the firewall is already hardened properly by Red Hat.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Unfortunately I do not have that option. This is a mandatory task...

Comment: You need to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just allow your "IP address through", you need to allow your IP in and out before setting the default policy. So, **before** any other iptables commands run something like this:

`iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.241.1 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.241.1 -j ACCEPT`

(Of course substitute 192.168.241.1 for your IP address.)

In real life though we normally do stuff a bit more elegantly, but in your specific task/situation/question this should give your IP free access you want.

It should be noted that default DROP policies without any amendments will disrupt many basic network functionalities. If this is a school lab or something, next steps are probably allowing basic networking functionalities with iptables again.